# How can I make an image fit inside a div element when the image is wider than the div?

Tags: html

I've an image tag inside a div element.

```
<div id = "myDiv">
 <img alt = "myImage" src = "some_source"/>
</div>
```

The image is bigger than the div, so the image is not inside the div element. First, I've thought about using **width = x, height = y**. But as I'm still designing the page, I fear to have to worry all the time those 2 dimensions.

How can I keep the image inside the div element? also, respecting the dimensions of the div element?

Thanks for helping

Comment: In your CSS, you could use `#myDiv > img { max-width: 100%; height: auto; }`. If the `div#myDiv` becomes larger than the picture, the picture will stay at it's full resolution width.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From here: [Three ways to resize images to fit a DIV](http://www.webmasterworld.com/css/3828593.htm)

Using the STYLE attribute within the IMG tag to manually set the width or height for each image (essentially the same as #1).

```
<div id="img_box">
<img style="width: 100%;" src="path/to/horizontal_image.jpg" />
</div>
<div id="img_box">
<img style="height: 100%;" src="path/to/vertical_image.jpg" />
</div>
```

Hope it solves your problem.

Edit: Best solution is to actually resize the image with server-side script.
Scaling images in the browser does not usually work out very well.

Edit2: http://unstoppablerobotninja.com/entry/fluid-images

Comment: if the height to width ratio of the image is wrong, setting width to 100% will cause the height to overflow and vice-versa.

Comment: Yep, the automatic scaling will alter the aspect ratio. Only way to ensure 100% accuracy is server side script. Check the Edit #2.

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me .

```
 .myimg {width:200px; height:auto;}
```

Automatically re-sizes images in all browsers .

Comment: Also you can do `.myimg {max-width:100%; height:auto;}` to constrain the width if the image happens to be larger than the div. If not, then the default image size will be used. This seems like it could be useful for responsive layouts. The interesting part for me is that the css takes precedence over the width and height attributes, which I didn't know about.

Answer (score 1):

Guys after spending too much time looking around for an easier way to do this, I combine the info from research to do it like this: (simply using the `getimagesize()` function -if the height is larger than the width, echo an image tag with  a style having a height of 100% else echo the same image tag but with a style having a width of 100%);

```
$image = "path to your image";
$img_size = getimagesize($image);

if ($img_size[0] < $img_size[1]){echo " < img src= '$image'  style='height:100%;'>";}
else {echo "< img src= '$image'  style='width:100%;'>";}
```

Answer (score 1):

*Since this post is from a while ago, I figure I'd update it with a more modern way of doing this that requires no JS.*

I'd recommend using the CSS properties `background-size:cover` and `background-position: center` to stretch, crop, and position the image (using `background-image` to set the image to the div).

It will set the image to shrink or grow to fit the div entirely then crop off anything outside of the div. It is a great way to handle images of somewhat different shapes and sizes in a div.

**HTML**

```
<div class="flexbox-container">
  <div class="filled-with-image"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.flexbox-container {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-end;
  justify-content: center;
}

.filled-with-image {
  width: 50%;
  height:400px;
  background-image: url(http://unsplash.it/1500/1000?image=875);
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-position: center bottom;
}
```

[See the code here.](https://codepen.io/ImProGrammar/pen/ZeEBZp)

Comment: I want it to fit within the div... height wise and width wise